# For loop not working when testing p-values and AIC values for models with different datasets (R)

Tags: r, model, linear-regression

I built several different linear models, ran different sets of normal distributions on each of these models, and now, I want to extract p-values and AIC values for each model. The issue is, it seems like the p-values and AIC values are not being extracted on ten different occasions rather, only once (from the first tested dataset).

I am running a for loop because I wish to create a normal distribution ten different times and therefore, test 10 different normal distributions on my models (+ extract p-values and AIC values ten different times)

```
 # Create normal distribution

   for (i in 1:10) {
    N<-100
    M<- 2000
    SD1<- 500
    SD2<-50
    Slope <- 3
    Slope1 <- 2
    Intercept <- 0 
    B <-rnorm(N, M, SD1)
    C <-rnorm(N, M, SD1)

   # Building Models
    A <-Intercept+ Slope*B + Slope1*C + rnorm(N,0,SD2)
    data<-as.data.frame(cbind(A, B, C))

    M1<-lm(data$A~data$B)
    M2<-lm(data$A~data$C)
    M3<-lm(data$A~data$B + data$C)

   # p-values
    pM1 = {fstat <- summary(M1)$fstatistic
    pf(fstat[1], fstat[2], fstat[3], lower.tail=FALSE)}
    pM2 = {fstat <- summary(M2)$fstatistic
    pf(fstat[1], fstat[2], fstat[3], lower.tail=FALSE)}
    pM3 = {fstat <- summary(M3)$fstatistic
    pf(fstat[1], fstat[2], fstat[3], lower.tail=FALSE)}
   
   # AIC Values 
    aicM1 = AIC(M1)
    aicM2 = AIC(M2)
    aicM3 = AIC(M3)


   }
    
    summary <- cbind(pM1, pM2, pM3, aicM1, aicM2, aicM3)`
```

Comment: You are just overwriting the values in each loop. You never use the looping variable `i` anywhere. Something like `replicate()` would probably be more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake with `for` loops--you overwrite everything instead of saving the results of each iteration. You should pre-allocate an object to hold your results, and then fill in the results using the `i` index during the loop.

```
summary = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 6))
names(summary) = c('pM1', 'pM2', 'pM3', 'aicM1', 'aicM2', 'aicM3')
for (i in 1:10) {
  # ... 
  # the code in your loop stays the same
  # ...

  # but then at the end, put the results in the ith row, like this:
  summary[i, ] = list(pM1, pM2, pM3, aicM1, aicM2, aicM3)
}
```

There are also shortcuts for this, like `replicate()` as suggested by MrFlick.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes a lot of sense - I will also try the alternative suggested by MrFlick.

Comment: Could I get some advice on how to make use of the i index for a nested for loop?

Comment: Well, if you have a nested loop then you have two indexes. You might want to have a separate counter that keeps track of which result row to use. Or you might have a 2d structure for the results. I'd suggest asking a new question.